# How does Browser calculate cookie from Set-Cookie?

Tags: python, rest, http, cookies, browser

When I send a successful login request to a website and get a response, in the header is a Set-Cookie attribute and a redirect. My Browser calculates a Cookie attribute (only from the Set-Cookie it seems?) and sends it in the new request to the redirected URL.

I want to know how a Cookie is calculated on the client side. This seems to happen automatically even without a browser (if you use python requests library for example) and the cookie has some parameters from the received Set-Cookie, but not all of them, so additional algorithms seem to be involved(?)

Comment: What do you mean, "calculate" a cookie?

Comment: when I send a form with login data and no cookie at all, I get a Set-Cookie header-attribute, which encodes some values. then my browser sends back a Cookie header-attribute with some of the values and some new ones. I want to know which algorithms are responsible for the new ones.

Comment: Are any cookies sent in the first request (to the original URL)? Also, how different are the original URL and redirected URL?

Comment: no, with the login form I send no cookies at all. the redirect is basically example.com/login > example.com

Comment: What algorithms are responsible for the new cookies? Whatever algorithms are in the page's JavaScript that set them.

Comment: are you sure its not a standardized procedure? look at the morsel_to_cookie method here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/cookies/

Comment: @Phil, A website can send a cookie to the browser in the HTTP response header Set-Cookie or the JavaScript executed in the webpage can set cookies. There is no algorithm in the browser for cookie calculation as such. Any algorithm could be in the server backend code or JavaScript to set the cookie value.